# Add checkbox in a Multi-level Kendo Razor Grid withTabStrip detailtemplate and another grid

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I followed Kendo's example for C# MVC (razor) http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/detailtemplate
for building my nested 'grid-tabstrip-grid'. This is exactly how is mine:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.EmployeeViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(e => e.FirstName).Width(120);
        columns.Bound(e => e.LastName).Width(120);
        columns.Bound(e => e.Country).Width(120);
        columns.Bound(e => e.City).Width(120);
        columns.Bound(e => e.Title);
    })
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable()
    .Scrollable()
    .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(5)
        .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_Employees", "Grid"))
    )
    .Events(events => events.DataBound("dataBound"))
)

<script id="template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
            .Name("tabStrip_#=EmployeeID#")
            .SelectedIndex(0)
            .Animation(animation => animation.Open(open => open.Fade(FadeDirection.In)))
            .Items(items =>
            {
                items.Add().Text("Orders").Content(@<text>
                    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.OrderViewModel>()
                        .Name("grid_#=EmployeeID#")
                        .Columns(columns =>
                        {
                            columns.Bound(o => o.OrderID).Title("ID").Width(56);
                            columns.Bound(o => o.ShipCountry).Width(110);
                            columns.Bound(o => o.ShipAddress);
                            columns.Bound(o => o.ShipName).Width(190);
                        })
                        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                            .Ajax()
                            .PageSize(5)
                            .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_Orders", "Grid", new { employeeID = "#=EmployeeID#" }))
                        )
                        .Pageable()
                        .Sortable()
                        .ToClientTemplate())
                </text>                        
                );
                items.Add().Text("Contact Information").Content(
                    "<div class='employee-details'>" +
                        "<ul>" +
                            "<li><label>Country:</label>#= Country #</li>" +
                            "<li><label>City:</label>#= City #</li>" +
                            "<li><label>Address:</label>#= Address #</li>" +
                            "<li><label>Home Phone:</label>#= HomePhone #</li>" +
                        "</ul>" +
                    "</div>"
                );                
            })
            .ToClientTemplate())
</script>

<script>
    function dataBound() {
        this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
    }
</script>

<style scoped="scoped">
    .k-detail-cell .k-tabstrip .k-content {
        padding: 0.2em;
    }
    .employee-details ul
    {
        list-style:none;
        font-style:italic;
        margin: 15px;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .employee-details ul li
    {
        margin: 0;
        line-height: 1.7em;
    }

    .employee-details label
    {
        display:inline-block;
        width:90px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        text-align: right;
        font-style:normal;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
</style>
```

My problem is when I try to add a checkbox for one of my boolean values within the 2nd (deepest) grid (see the grid with .Name("grid_#=EmployeeID#") above) . It would not accept common answers i found. How should i do this:

```
columns.Bound(o => o.ShortListedFlag).Title("Short Listed").ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' #= ShortListedFlag ? checked='checked': '' # class='chkbx' />");
```

Comment: Tried multiple ways of writing the field ie. //#=ShortListedFlag ? checked='checked': '' #//

Comment: first fix this... ShortListedFlag ? checked='checked': '' then try  \\# if it is nested.